# How do I write this equation in einstein notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am a programmer who does quite a bit of maths.

One of the operations in my code is the operation: `C = np.einsum("ij,kj->ki",A,B)` ([the documentation for his function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)).

The dimensions of the matricies (is it right to call these matricies?) are:

- `A`:`m by n`
- `B`:`p by n`
- `C`: `m by p`

Ultimately my question is, how do I write the operation of `C = np.einsum("ij,kj->ki",A,B)` in a purely mathematical context?

I have looked through a few examples, but I have had difficulty connecting these to what I am doing.

(I apologise if the tags and/or the title are/is bad, please drop a comment and I'll correct it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is
$$
C = BA^t.
$$
That's because what's computed is
$$
c_{ki} = \sum_j a_{ij} b_{kj} \tag{1}
$$
and denoting by $a'$ the elements of the transpose of $a$ for the moment, we have
$$
a'_{pq} = a_{qp}
$$
so
$$
a_{ij} = a'_{ji}
$$
and Equation 1 can be written
\begin{align}
c_{ki} 
&= \sum_j a_{ij} b_{kj} \\
&= \sum_j a'_{ji} b_{kj}\\
&= \sum_j b_{kj} a'_{ji}  
\end{align}
Swapping indices $i$ and $k$, (i.e., replacing every occurrence of "i" with "k" and vice versa) this becomes
\begin{align}
c_{ik} 
&= \sum_j b_{ij} a'_{jk}  
\end{align}
and then swapping $j$ and $k$ we get
\begin{align}
c_{ij} 
&= \sum_k b_{ik} a'_{kj}  
\end{align}
which is the absolutely standard definition of matrix product for the matrices $B$ and $A' = A^t$.

Comment: It would seem I had laughably overcomplicated it. Thank you for simplifying it!

Comment: After the first ten times you do this, it gets a **lot** easier. All my time was spent either in typing or in verifying that my best-guess about the documentation was in fact correct. The "thinking" part took about 5 seconds (and then 5 more to realize I'd missing one thing...)

Comment: Why not $A^{i}{}_{j}B^{j}{}_{k}=C^{i}{}_{k}$?

Comment: Because you have the "k" and "j" indices on the $B$ swapped, and the "k" and "i" indices on the $C$ swapped. The input says `ij,kj->ki` indicating $A_j^i$ and $B_j^k$, with `ki` indicating the indices on the **output**, namely $C$.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean that $A^{i}{}_{j}B^{j}{}_{k}=C^{k}{}_{i}$ would be correct?

Comment: No. If you assume that `ij` means "upper $i$, lower $j$", then your $B$ indexes would have to be $\left.B^k\right._j$.

Comment: $A^{i}{}_{j}B^{k}{}_{j}=C^{k}{}_{i}$?

Comment: Yep...that's right (unless the correct rule for `ij` is "upper j, lower i"). Frankly, I've never gotten "uppers" and "lowers" straight in my head, and that's even after teaching differential geometry courses 3 times. But at least what you've written is **consistent** with the `ij,kj -> ki` expression.

Comment: It is, at least counter-intuitive, because in matrix multiplication you match column index with row index, so the dummy index here should either be up-down or down-up... I'm sure you're right, but I don't get it.

Comment: Right...now transpose $A$ and it puts the $j$ up and the $i$ down, so $BA^t$ makes perfect sense.

Comment: One last recap... So the more meaningful way of expressing it would probably be $B^{k}{}_{j}A^{j}{}_{i}=C^{k}{}_{i}$... (Thank you for your last comment clarifying the upper / down issue).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115261/discussion-between-antoni-parellada-and-john-hughes).

Comment: Thank you very much for your generous additional explanations to all these follow-up questions.